# What is "n6" in transparent architecture (NG-RAN)?

Tags: networking, interface, standardisation, 5g

[image]

Hello everyone!

I study the NG-RAN logical architecture described in TS 38.401, baseline for NTN scenarios.

I have found the picture of transparent architecture, you see below. I can not find a description what "n6" connection between 5GC and data network mean

Comment: I found some explanation here: https://emblasoft.com/blog/the-importance-of-testing-the-5g-n6-and-4g-sgi-interfaces#:~:text=The%20N6%20interface%20plays%20the,public%20cloud%20or%20private%20clouds